# Creating CTE with rows defined in query without using union all

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm thinking of something like this but cannot get the syntax right

```sql
WITH cte_name (dog, name) AS (
VALUES
  ('dog1', 'name1'),
  ('dog2', 'name2'),
  ('dog3', 'name3'),
  ('dog4', 'name4'),
  ('dog5', 'name5')
)
SELECT * FROM cte_name;
```

or

```sql
WITH A AS (
    SELECT '2023-11-01' AS date, 'November' AS month
)
INSERT INTO A (date, month)
VALUES ('2023-10-01',  'October')
```

Edit: I have found this way but I hope there's a cleaner way

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE A AS (
    SELECT '2023-11-01' AS date, 'November' AS month
);
INSERT INTO A (date, month)
VALUES ('2023-10-01',  'October')
```

Comment: What is the reason to exclude UNION or UNION ALL ?

Comment: Cleaner as I need to create CTE's with many rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below option - close enough to your what you are looking for

```
WITH cte_name AS (
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
  STRUCT('dog1' as dog, 'name1' as name),
  ('dog2', 'name2'),
  ('dog3', 'name3'),
  ('dog4', 'name4'),
  ('dog5', 'name5')
  ]) 
)
SELECT * FROM cte_name;
```

Comment: Legend, that is what I'm looking for and I've learnt a new bit of functionality

Answer (score -1):

I have the same idea as @[yotheguitou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20285843/yotheguitou), to use UNION ALL.

```
WITH cte_name AS (
  SELECT "dog1" AS dog, "name1" AS name 
  UNION ALL SELECT "dog2" AS dog, "name2" AS name 
  UNION ALL SELECT "dog3" AS dog, "name3" AS name
  UNION ALL SELECT "dog4" AS dog, "name4" AS name
  UNION ALL SELECT "dog5" AS dog, "name5" AS name)
SELECT dog, name FROM cte_name;
```